# how can I print out values above average and return its years in numpy?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

i have a dataset which requires me to **print out values larger than the average with the years**. I'm able to retrieve the datas but not together with the years.
is there any efficient way i can use to display both datas together?
below is a snippet of the dataset with years and datas respectively.

`[2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017]`
`[29057,30979,31746,32964,31738,31010,31158,28736]`

can someone please suggest a method for this! appreciate it, cheers!

Comment: please provide the real object used for your data, do you have two lists or a numpy array?

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is not really explained I am not sure that is exactly what you except :

```py
date = [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017]
data = [29057,30979,31746,32964,31738,31010,31158,28736]

date_mean = np.mean(date)

for i,year in enumerate(date):
    if year > date_mean:
        print(year, data[i])
```

It print the following :

```
2014 31738
2015 31010
2016 31158
2017 28736
```

Answer (score 2):

Using numpy:

```
years = np.array([2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017])
data = np.array([29057,30979,31746,32964,31738,31010,31158,28736])

out = np.stack([years, data])[:, data>data.mean()]
```

output:

```
array([[ 2011,  2012,  2013,  2014,  2015,  2016],
       [30979, 31746, 32964, 31738, 31010, 31158]])
```

Answer (score 1):

To group your two lists together, you could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#zip).

Example:

```py
years = [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017]
values = [29057,30979,31746,32964,31738,31010,31158,28736]
pair = list(zip(years, values))
```

Output:

```
>>> pair
[(2010, 29057), (2011, 30979), (2012, 31746), (2013, 32964), (2014, 31738), (2015, 31010), (2016, 31158), (2017, 28736)]
```

---

To get the values above the mean, you can use the following snippet:

```
above_mean = [i for i in pair if i[1] > sum(values)/len(values)]
```

Output:

```
>>> above_mean
[(2011, 30979), (2012, 31746), (2013, 32964), (2014, 31738), (2015, 31010), (2016, 31158)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the date with a condition in array and the get the corresponding x with.index()

```js
date = [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017]

x = [29057,30979,31746,32964,31738,31010,31158,28736]

year = [d for d in date if d >= (np.mean(date))]

for d in year:
    
    print(d, x[date.index(d)])

>>>2014 31738
2015 31010
2016 31158
2017 28736
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.c_[y[x>x.mean()], x[x>x.mean()]]

#output:
array([[ 2011, 30979],
       [ 2012, 31746],
       [ 2013, 32964],
       [ 2014, 31738],
       [ 2015, 31010],
       [ 2016, 31158]])
```

`x>x.mean()` returns a boolean mask (`True` is `x>x.mean()` and `False` otherwise); we can use this mask to select `x` values higher than the mean with `x[x>x.mean()]`. In the same way we can select the years in which `x>x.mean()` with `y[x>x.mean()]` (you can try an see the output of these two lines). Now we have 2 arrays of same size and we can stack them together with `np.c_`, in order to have a matrix of two columns (the first column for the years and the second for the `x` values).